# HTML design problem with alignment

Tags: html, alignment

Please consider the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Sign In</title>
</head>

<body bgcolor="#DDDDDD">
<img src="images/logo.png" style="float:right; margin: 0 0 15px 15px;"/> 
<div align="center">
<table border="0" width="500" style="border:groove;background:#DCD5F9">
<tr><td width="50%">User Name:</td> <td width="55%"><input type="text" size="35"/></td></tr>
<tr><td width="50%">Password:</td> <td width="55%"><input type="text" size="35"/></td></tr> 
<tr><td width="50%">&nbsp; </td> <td align="left" width="55%"> <input type="submit" value="Login"/></td></tr>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

In browser I see that the `<div>` is not under the `logo.png`. Why? And how I can make it to be under the logo.png?

P.S. I would like to add that problem occured when I added the `style="float:right; margin: 0 0 15px 15px;"` or `align="right"` in `<img>` tag.

Comment: What do you mean by "Under the Image"

Do you mean the content is overlapping, or you want the text underneath and inline (vertically) with the image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you've added the float:right on your img which changes how the img will behave in the page flow. Forcing the div to clear content will fix your issue.

change this:

```
<div align="center">
```

to:

```
<div align="center" style="clear:right;">
```

From Wikipedia:

"[A floated item is taken out of the normal flow and shifted to the left or right as far as possible in the space available. Other content then flows alongside the floated item.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets)"

Comment: Thanks! It worked but you did not explain what was the problem.

Comment: Added more detail. Hope this answers your question.